# irrarional numbers and their propertirs

Tags: real-analysis, irrational-numbers

How are two irrational numbers added and multiplied and what is the proof behind it.

I have looked through several books but none seem to have the answer

Comment: How are the two irrational numbers given?

Comment: Study the "Dedekind cut", see for example Rudin's book "principles of mathematical analysis" page 17-21.

Comment: To answer this it is equivalent to asking how real numbers in general are formally defined and added and multiplied.  One strategy is to define the real numbers as equivalence classes of convergent sequences of rational numbers, the real number being the limit of the class of sequences.  In such a definition, you have $x\cdot y = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n\cdot y_n$, the multiplication on the right being just multiplication of rational numbers which we already know how to do.

Comment: As you can see, you're getting some pretty advanced responses here - if that's not what you're going for, it would help to clarify a bit (see lhf's comment above) or to give an example of a situation you're interested in.

Comment: As an aside... "*what is the proof behind it*"  You can't prove a definition.  We can *define* what real numbers are, and we can *define* what addition of real numbers is, and we can prove things about the results of having defined things in this way... but we can't *prove* addition.

Comment: See: David Herbert Fowler, [*Dedekind's theorem:* $\sqrt{2} \times \sqrt{3} = \sqrt{6}$](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2324238), **American Mathematical Monthly** 99 #8 (October 1992), pp. 725-733.